# Calling C++ vs writing php function?

Tags: php, c++, exec

I am trying to think which would be better. I could just do some benchmarks, but doing one or two examples might not be as useful as getting others insight.  I am trying to do some math and I was thinking about writing a program in C++ and use pipes to get the data around. What is the overhead of doing an exec and is there a general guide line of when one method would be faster than the other?

Comment: I would think this depends what you are trying to calculate? Could you give an example of you mean by "do some math"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks ago, I tested the speed of C/Cpp vs the speed of PHP with different for-loops (about 1x10⁶ times).

---

> The simple loops, like basic or slightly complicated math operations,
>   showed just a really little time difference. I don't remember exactly
>   anymore, but something about 1 to 3 Seconds (For 1x10⁶ operations).

-

> For more complex functions, e.g. String-Operations applied to big
>   texts or real big and complex maths, the time difference is bigger. In my case, for parsing a big text, and this a million times, the time difference was about 5 - 10 Minutes.

**Slightly Offtopic* * Critical is also the recreation of PHP functions, the implemented functions will always be faster. If there is a PHP-Function for something, use it.

I hope this helped a little bit.
Greets

Answer (score -2):

PHP is easily accessible. It is all accessible through a webpage and it much easier to display. It's inherently built with many mathematical functions and databases such as MySQL and MongoDB make it extremely easy to come back with the data.

Comment: That doesn't really address that question...

Comment: Perhaps the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: No, the question is **super**-clear (it's arguably not a good question that has constructive answers in its current form, but that's not the point).

Comment: This is coming in one ear and out the other. All it seems like to me is that he wants to 'do some math' but can't decide between PHP and C++.

Comment: So OP knows that he can do what he wants with both PHP and C++ and wants to know which one is faster, and your answer to that is a vague list of general features of PHP together with a completely unrelated reference to MySQL and MongoDB? Nice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I stated that it's accessible through a website, that would imply it is quicker. The reference to databases was "and use pipes to get the data around." Specifics are necessities. If the OP was **super**-clear, then I would've been **super**-clear. A common misconception on StackOverflow is that if someone is relatively specific so that others can answer, that means that if one gives an incorrect or invalid answer, they're oblivious to the world around them.

Comment: I'm not saying you're oblivious to the world around you, I'm saying that you (deliberately or inadvertently?) are misinterpreting the question. OP has existing PHP code and wants to do some calculations. He's wondering whether to implement them in PHP or call external C++ functions. As an example, let's say he gets a graph as user input and wants to compute a minimal spanning tree. You can do that in PHP or pass the data to C++ and get it back. That has *nothing* to do with databases, and *nothing* to do with "accessible through webpage/easier to display".

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I'm sure that when someone misinterprets a question, they're not intentionally doing so.